# expectation derivations on a Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume $R$ is Gaussian random variable. I read this from a paper,$\newcommand{var}{\text{Var}}$

$$\mathbb{E}[1-\exp\{-\lambda R\}] = 1-\exp\{-\lambda \mathbb{E}(R) + \frac{\lambda^2}{2}\var(R)\}$$

and,$\newcommand{argmax}{\text{arg max}}$

$$\argmax_{a} 1-\exp\{-\lambda \mathbb{E}(R) + \frac{\lambda^2}{2}Var(R)\} = \argmax_a \mathbb{E}(R) - \frac{\lambda}{2}\var(R)$$

where $a$ is a parameter in $R$.

I didn't figure out the derivation steps. Could you please give me some hints on how to get this? Thanks!

Comment: Since $R$ is a Gaussian random variable, what does "$a$ is a parameter in $R$" mean?  That $a$ is the mean $\mu$ or the variance $\sigma^2$ (these are the only two parameters defining a Gaussian distribution) or some function of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$?

Comment: @Dilip I guess it does not matter in which way $R$ is parametrized by $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first formula, it was used that $\mathsf E[1-x] = 1-\mathsf Ex$, and then the formula for the [MGT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) of the Gaussian random variable (see examples in the linked article) was applied. For the second, you have that$\newcommand{argmax}{\operatorname{arg max}}$
$$
f(a) = \lambda\mathsf E(R_a)-\frac{\lambda^2}2\mathsf V(R_a)
$$
is just *some* function of $a$. Moreover, the function 
$$
g(y) = 1-\mathrm e^{-y}
$$
is *strictly increasing* for all $y\in\mathbb R$. That easily implies
$$
\argmax_a g(f(a)) = \argmax_a f(a)
$$

Comment: That's clear and helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I would like to revise a bit: $$g(y) = 1-e^{-\lambda y}$$ and it's strictly increasing for all positive $\lambda$.

Comment: @Shuai: thanks, I've fixed in in the other way